# Could VLQ get the convert to comment option in the mod queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts

A lot of people seem to use VLQ when they really mean Not An Answer. Many [can't see the difference](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/why-do-we-have-the-very-low-quality-flag). I, personally, know the difference but find VLQ to be a rather rare flag if used properly.

However, "very low quality" is much clearer than "not an answer", and I find users (even Community!) using VLQ where NAA makes more sense. This is a problem, but I don't have any idea how to fix it so I'll jist focus on the symptoms.

When an NAA flag appears in the queue, there is a direct option to convert to comment. Could VLQ have this as well? It's much easier to handle flags from within the queue whenever possible.

Suggestions on how to improve the central problem also welcome.

Comment: I didn't know Community raised VLQ flags. I thought it only handled them.

Comment: @BoltClock I bet he's talking about the Low Quality Score flags.

Comment: @Undo the Snowman: Oh.

Comment: "Suggestions on how to improve the central problem also welcome." Can someone round up the links to all the "rename the VLQ flag" requests here.